# how check string is integer or not by using spring annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**i want test user input is a alpha-numeric or integer by using spring form annotations **

> ```
> i have also tried this code.
> ```

```
 @NotEmpty
        @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
        @Length(min =11,max =11)
        @Column(name="abc")
        private String xyz;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@NumberFormat` [annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.html) only applies to subclasses of java.lang.Number ([Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), [Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html), [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), etc.); therefore, it won't work with Strings. For this, you may have to create a custom annotation that validates the String only contains numbers.

Take a look at the following tutorial; it's very thorough on how to create custom annotations and use them for validation with Spring: http://softwarecave.org/2014/03/27/custom-bean-validation-constraints/

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a similar problem and used the `@Pattern` annotation to compare against a regular expression.

```
@Pattern(regexp="^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$")
```

The annotation is part of the `javax.validation.constraints` package.

Comment: @Pattern is not getting evaluated for me.